# Populating a listview with a tweet array using an array adapter

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, twitter

I am trying to populate my listview with my tweets array but I either throw an error or the app crashes on startup.  Can anyone help me ensure I have the proper syntax or let me know if I have something out of place?  The error is in my `TweetAdapter` class and it is annotated in the code.  The error states `Cannot resolve method 'super(android.app.Activity, int, java.lang.String[])'`

This is the code from my TweetAdapter class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import s607central.pettastic.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    private List<Tweet> tweetList;

    public TweetAdapter(Activity activity, String[] items){  

        super(activity, R.layout.row_tweet, items); // **THIS IS THE ERROR**
        inflater = activity.getWindow().getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tweet_detail, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweetTitle);
        TextView tb = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweetBody);
        Tweet t = tweetList.get(position);


        return convertView;
```

In case it's relevant, this is the code from my TweetListActivity class, there are no errors here:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class TweetListActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayAdapter tweetItemArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweet_list);

        List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();



        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
            tweet.setTitle("A nice header for Tweet # " + i);
            tweet.setBody("Some random body text for the tweet # " + i);
            tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
            tweets.add(tweet);
        }


        tweetItemArrayAdapter = new TweetAdapter(this, new String[10]);
        setListAdapter(tweetItemArrayAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TweetDetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you the method you're trying to call doesn't exist.

I assume you're trying to use the [`ArrayAdapter(Context, int, T[])`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20T[])) constructor.

The reason it's not working is because you're parameterizing your class with `Tweet`, so you need to pass down `Tweet[]`, not `String[]`. Either that, or change your class to be defined with `extends ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: I've tried both methods, using String takes away the errors but the app still crashes on launch.  When I use Tweet[] that just throws more errors.

Comment: Getting it compiling is the first step, and the problem as you've defined in this question. Compile errors are very different than runtime errors: once it compiles you can run it and see where/why it crashes.